# Using pytorch Dataloader in pytorch kmeans

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, k-means

I'm Trying to perform a Kmeans clusterization using the Pytorch-kmeans ([github](https://github.com/subhadarship/kmeans_pytorch)). I have aprox. 27M array with 512 elements each, the aprox. size of the numpy array is 51GB which is bigger than my GPU RAM (32GB). Is there a way I can batch the arrays using the pytorch DataLoader class?

Comment: what is the source of data? is it a CSV?

Comment: It is a numpy array saved as .npy

Comment: I'd just use the CPU for this one. Pushing huge chunks of data back and forth to the GPU will probably be slower.